# How to check for a part of a string in a class NoneType with tuples in python?

Tags: python, tuples

I want to iterate through a set objects from the self defined class 'Movie', each Movie object contains tuples which look like:

```
(Observation(DetailType='Genre', Genres=("crime", "drama"), Oscar=None), Observation(DetailType='Oscar', valueCode=None, Oscar=True))
```

For each Movie object I want to make a boolean feature which can only be true if:

For DetailType='Genre' -> Genres contains ("crime" AND "drama") OR ("horror")

AND

For DetailType='Oscar' -> Oscar=True

Comment: These aren't `NoneType`, they are tuples.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, I have changed the question!

Answer (score 1):

```py
class Observation:
    def __init__(self, DetailType, Genres=None, Oscar=None, valueCode=None):
        self.DetailType = DetailType
        self.Genres = Genres
        self.Oscar = Oscar
        self.valueCode = valueCode


def check_observation(observation):
    is_genre = observation.DetailType == "Genre"
    is_oscar = observation.DetailType == "Oscar"

    if is_genre:
        is_drama_or_crime = (
            "crime" in observation.Genres or "drama" in observation.Genres
        )
        is_horror = "horror" in observation.Genres
        return is_drama_or_crime or is_horror
    elif is_oscar:
        return observation.Oscar is True
    else:
        # Observation type is neither Gerne nor Oscar
        return None


observations = (
    Observation(DetailType="Genre", Genres=("crime", "drama"), Oscar=None),
    Observation(DetailType="Oscar", valueCode=None, Oscar=True),
)

for observation in observations:
    print(check_observation(observation))
```

Returns:

```py
True
True
```

---

*Previous answer:*

You can use `"Text1" in ('Text1','Variant1')` to check whether a tuple contains an item with the value `Text1`.

```py
>>> my_tuple = ("Text1", "Variant1")

>>> "Text1" in my_tuple
True

>>> "Variant1" in my_tuple
True

>>> "Variant2" in my_tuple
False

>>> feature = (
>>>     ("Text1" in my_tuple and "Variant2" in my_tuple)
>>>     or ("Text2" in my_tuple)
>>>     or ("Variant3" in my_tuple)
>>> )

>>> print(feature)
False
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have the following error: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: Can you show more of your code to help us understand your problem better?

Comment: I have formulated the question in another way to show the context of my problem, I hope this helps?

Comment: It worked, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```py
def contains(my_tuple, elem):
    return elem in set(my_tuple)

my_tuple = ("Text1", "Variant1")

print(contains(my_tuple, "Text1"))      # prints True
print(contains(my_tuple, "Variant2"))   # prints False
```